# We got a nasty shock

Tags: riddle, knowledge, history

Our polarity was mentioned but never revealed

Coulombs we made, but our fate was sealed

Repelling the dark, we refused to yield

They had a battery: We died in the field

**Who are we and how many?**  (Please explain each line)

---

**Hints**

1. If we had been switched on, we might have better seen our fate. But, then again, it did happen during the day.

Comment: @bobble - I've added the riddle tag.  You are asked to identify "we", a historically recorded group. Note that I have consistently used misdirection. Once that has been bypassed, everything makes sense provided you know or can glean the history.

Comment: @csM - I suppose that means you're not referring to 6 billion electrons?

Comment: @Nilster - Correct. I am not!  You could call it a species of indirect pun.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wonder whether this is

> a terrible pun on The *Charge* of the Light Brigade, as immortalized by Tennyson's poem.

If so then

> "we" are the British light cavalry who on 1854-10-25 made an ill-fated attack on the Russian artillery, and according to Tennyson the number is 600. (The actual number of deaths was quite a lot less than that. I don't know exactly how many soldiers were really involved.)

Our polarity was mentioned but never revealed

> That is, our *charge*. It's even in the title! But Tennyson inexplicably neglects to say whether it was a positive or a negative charge.

Coulombs we made, but our fate was sealed

> Once again, they made a *charge*. But "all the world knew / Someone had blundered", and they were doomed to "do and die".

Repelling the dark, we refused to yield

> They were of course the *Light* brigade. "Boldly they rode and well, / Into the jaws of Death, / Into the mouth of Hell."

They had a battery: We died in the field

> Quite a considerable battery. Cannons to the left of them, cannons to the right of them. Tennyson even uses the word: "Plunged in the battery-smoke / Right thro' the line they broke". But, alas, many of them died. It was, of course, not actually an *electric* field.

Comment: Wow - That was quick!